ASP.NET application doesn't work after cloning project
C# ASP.NET project made with Visual Studio.
I cloned it copying the folder project in another place. Dependencies with relative paths were broken and I carefully added them again. I can build the project but it generates an exception and doesn't work. The Myapp.deps.json generated by Visual Studio is slightly different from the original project, it lacks two .dll
...  
"DnsClient/1.3.1.0": {
    "runtime": {
      "DnsClient.dll": {
        "assemblyVersion": "1.3.1.0",
        "fileVersion": "1.3.1.0"
      }
    }
  },
  "SharpCompress/0.23.0.0": {
    "runtime": {
      "SharpCompress.dll": {
        "assemblyVersion": "0.23.0.0",
        "fileVersion": "0.23.0.0"
      }
    }
 ...
"libraries": {
...
"DnsClient/1.3.1.0": {
  "type": "reference",
  "serviceable": false,
  "sha512": ""
},
"SharpCompress/0.23.0.0": {
  "type": "reference",
  "serviceable": false,
  "sha512": ""
}

The file is automatically generated and I cannot find any reason because they are different.
The missing dll above are not listed in the dependencies and I don't know where they come from.
Update 1
In the second project I cleared all the references, then I created a folder and copied all the dll found in the first project. They are 17, the assembly references in Visual Studio are only 12. I added again the 12 assembly references, this time they are all in the same directory together with other 5 dll (DnsClient.dll is one of them). After building Myapp.deps.json contains DnsClient and SharpCompress. I suppose Visual Studio makes some checks on the referenced assemblies and automatically adds other dll they need if it find them in the same folder. I have no other explanation.

Can you provide detailed steps to help us reproduce your problem?

It is not easy ,I should  upload the project and currently cannot do it. As already stated the project uses MongoDB driver and creates an instance of MongoClient passing a connection string, localhost:5000. It seems that DnsClient.dll is needed but it is not an explicit dependency. I'm almost sure that a desktop project works fine without that dll.

Learn to use a SCM tool like Git. Don't "cloned it copying the folder project in another place".

These are the common steps, as it will lead to an answer:

Delete the bin and obj folders at each directory within the cloned project.
Perform a clean build
Try a tool like Beyond Compare to compare the cloned project to the working version, compare at highest level folder, include all contents and sub folders.
Try checking the working project into GitHub, and checking it out to a new location and see if it builds, you'll want to preserve the working copy anyways when fiddling around.
Perform the Nuget commands and check your Nuget package manager for any concern. Nuget restore: dotnet build, dotnet run, dotnet restore are some common commands.
Sometimes even modifying an auto generated file can break things keep in mind!
As a last resort just build a fresh empty .NET solution and just add your code files to the new project, sometimes the project can contain an unknown error.
If you did clone using Git, then was any files missing from the check-in?
Check your included dlls
Finally a binary approach is to create an empty .NET project and add copy things in from the working version one at a time building the project until you get or do not get the failure, also try comparing your .sln files and csproj and configs.

These steps will get it working. What error do you see when running the project?

About the error: the application uses MongoDb driver and when the class is instantiated there is an exception, Constructor The type initializer for 'MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.DnsClientWrapper' threw an exception. It leads me to think DnsClient.dll is needed and if I manually add it there is no exception, but on the original project it is automatically added and it is not listed in the references.
